# Apache htaccess 301 redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to rewrite url from article.php?id=123 to article/123

I added the following rule, it works fine

```
  RewriteRule ^article/(.*) /article.php?id=$1 [PT]
```

I also want to add a 301 redirect rule to let search engine know article.php?id=123 should move to article/123. I added the following rule but seems not working.

```
  RewriteRule ^article.php?id=(.*)$ /article/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to match against the *actual request* and not the URI because the URI gets rewritten by other rules:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /article\.php\?id=([^\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^article\.php$ /article/%1? [R=301,L]
```

If you don't match against the actual request, a redirect loop will occur:

1. Browser requests `/article.php?id=123`
2. Server redirects to `/article/123`
3. Browser requests `/article/123`
4. Server rewrites internally to `/article.php?id=123`
5. Server internally matches and redirects the browser to `/article/123`
6. Browser requests `/article/123`
7. repeat from 4.

Comment: Thanks! I tried but still can not see 301 redirect using this `http://www.internetofficer.com/seo-tool/redirect-check/`

Comment: @Sophia The rule works for me when I put it in an empty htaccess file in my document root for a vanilla apache server and I request `http://localhost/article.php?id=123`, I get redirected to `http://localhost/article/123`

Comment: Do you have `RewriteRule ^article/(.*) /article.php?id=$1 [PT]` in your htaccess file also?

Comment: @Sophia Yes, I have both. After the redirect, I get served the article.php page

Comment: Thanks Jon! what's mean of `[A-Z]{3,9}` and how to let the id not only numbers but also words.

Comment: @Sophia The `[A-Z]{3,9}` means all capital letters between lengths 3 and 9, the `[^\ ]+` will match anything that's **not** a space (which includes all numbers or letters).

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
RewriteRule ^article.php?id=(.*)$ /article/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I use this website `http://www.internetofficer.com/seo-tool/redirect-check/` to check 301 redirect. I changed to `[L, R=301]`. Still not working.

Comment: This rule won't work because apache will think the `RewriteRule` will have 4 parameters, the match, the target, a flag `[L,` and the flag `R=301]`, which is incorrect syntax, the flags inside square brackets can't be separated by spaces: `[L,R=301]`