# htaccess RewriteCond and RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm actually working on a little php webiste and i decided to try to give it some nice and cleans urls using a htaccess file. I've read some docs about it and created a simple file with a few rules, things is it's working but partially.

This is what I did:
I added a RewriteRule to redirect "www.mysite.com/hello" to "www.mysite.com/index.php?action=hello".

This is working fine, problem is i want to hide the "index.php?action=" part if it ever appears. So if somoene imputs something like "www.mysite.com/index.php?action=hello" it will be converted to www.mysite.com/hello" in the url field.

For this i wrote the following:

```
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\?action=([^\ ]+)
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /%1? [R=301,L]
```

Sadly it only hides the index.php part of the url, the "?action=" part is still there.

What did i do wrong?

Regards.

Edit: i'm testing this on local in wamp

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty close. The regex in the rule is trying to match `article.php` but the condition says that the request must be for `index.php`, so it's unlikely the rule will ever run. Try:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\?action=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?action=$1 [QSA,L]
```

and make sure the rule is **before** the rule that rewrites internally back to `index.php`.

Comment: i keep doing something wrong, i did the changes but not only it doesnt work as planned but it's seems that it's blocking the loading of my js and css files... I'll post my code in a sec: `RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\?action=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?action=$1 [QSA,L]`

Comment: also corrected article.php, it was a typo i made when i wrote the code on the forum, my actual file had index.php. edit: it seems that i got this code from you in the first place when i was browsing the forum hehe (http://stackoverflow.com/a/11638279)

Comment: @g6431827 your conditions are all jumbled up. By *before*, I mean before the conditions too. Rewrite conditions only apply to the immediately following rule, you can't just stick new stuff between conditions and rules. Conditions and rules must be together and in the right order.

Comment: ok so i dumped the less usefull stuff to make things easier for me: i'm only left with 4 sentences. The first one is `RewriteEngine On`, then the second is `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?action=$1 [QSA,L]`. This should redirect any requests like "www.mysite.com/hello" to "www.mysite.com/index.php?action=hello", right? Third i have `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\?action=([^&\ ]+)`. And finally `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /%1? [R=301,L]`

Comment: @g6431827 no, you want the redirect rule (with the `R` flag) to be **before** the rule that rewrites to `index.php`. And you need those conditions that you had against the index.php rewrite or they won't work.

Comment: thanks for the edit, but it still fails... maybe i should change some wamp config files, i dunno. i used the code you gave me and when i type "http://localhost/website/index.php?action=hello" the url still dont convert to "http://localhost/Template/hello". Anyway i'll try to get some sleep and i'll retry this a bit later. (being tired dont help hehe)

Comment: @g6431827 your question doesn't mention anything about `/website/index.php` or `/Template/`. That changes everything. You need to change *all* of the paths in the rules to match those exactly.

Comment: oh so when i test stuff in local it's different from what it's going to be like when i put it online? I mean i though the root directory of my project (which is now template [it was website but i renamed it by now] located in www folder of wamp) was the same thing as www.mywebsite.com if i put it online. guess i'm wrong :p